# Add dependency for subproject in gradle from root build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have a unique situation where I have to distribute an Android library project which is imported as a module (let's call it `:my-module`) into a main Android app project, but that module depends on a third party library (AAR) that legally cannot be distributed with the module.

Thus, I need to be able to let the developer of the app download and specify the dependency, but they cannot modify the Android library.

I was trying to find a way to specify the path to the AAR file in the root `build.gradle` such that it applied only to the `:my-module` project, but I am struggling to figure out how to specify dependencies from the root `build.gradle` such that they apply to the sub-module `:my-module`). Is this possible?

Comment: First thing that came to my mind that to try ```allProjects``` block in project level `build.gradle` file. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks @Mirjalal. I have tried putting an allprojects block in both the root and `app/build.gradle` files. Putting one in `app/build.gradle` syncs but the sub-module cannot see the dependency for some reason so the project doesn't compile